# (JPA) Append condition in ON clause during Joins

Tags: jpa, jpql

I need the JPQL in this format:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN Address a ON p.id = a.id AND a.flat = 100;
```

But when i run the code the query being slightly modified henceforth the output of data changed..

```
SELECT * FROM Person p LEFT JOIN Address a ON p.id = a.id where a.flat = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to format the sql output.

So for hibernate, you can set `hibernate.format_sql=true` to well format the sql.

If you are using spring boot, you can config it via `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true` simply.

Comment: I don't need formatting here rather i need the exact sql which fetch the exact result those were coming from the previous one. My first query returns 3 records, and second query return only 1 which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

JPQL does not allow joining to arbitrary other root objects, so you can't do that in JPQL; only allowing you to join along relations. Individual vendors may offer a vendor extension to allow joining across arbitrary roots but you then lose portability.

To provide more than that you have to post the actual JPA entities, and you haven't.